# PHP Array combining 2 or more values together

Tags: php, arrays, datamapper, dynamic-arrays

I am curious know if and how it is possible to combine 2 values of an array together instead of overriding the other. I will show you an example:

I have a form that is mapping fields to a database from a CSV file. The problem I am running into is say for example there are 2 address fields that need to be merged into 1 address field in my database. (IE: photo below)

[image]

So my problem comes when I look at the $_POST[] array. It will show that there are 2 HOME ADDRESSES Selected and import into my database with the LAST selected home-address.

How can I merge the information into 1. I hope this gives you enough information on my problem, please let me know if you need something specific.

I am dealing with all arrays, and when I post into my database it requires an Array to loop through, as I use a reflection class. I hope this makes sense...

Any light would be appreciated on this matter. 
Cheers,

I appreciate the quite comments back, the problem that I have with your responses is that I can't create my inputs to be address[] as that will be dynamic and I won't know which one will be set to address and which would perhaps be set to 'phone'... I hope this new picture helps a bit in understanding.

Some of the code (Shortened):

```
<select name="Home_Address_1"> // name is dynamically generated from the CSV headings
  <option>...</option>
</select>
<select name="Home_Address_2"> // name is dynamically generated from the CSV headings
  <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: try naming the select tag like this `name="adress[]"` then you'll have `$_POST['adress'][0]` and `$_POST['adress'][1]` and use them as you please

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect your comments

Comment: if i understood you're question correctly you could use `array_merge_recursive($_POST)` try that and report back ;)

Comment: Hi Breezer, Thank you for the comment sorry for my slow reply, I was sick for a few days there... I have added some sample code to show what the form looks like here. I know it's complex but if you have any other ideas that would be greatly appreciated. The Merge Recursive won't work because of the Home_Address_1 and _2 are different and not the same as the recursive would need.

Answer (score 2):

Example of using two posted values in a single array:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input name="address[]" type="text" value="111" />
<input name="address[]" type="text" value="222" />
```

Notice the name attributes.

```
// PHP
$address = $_POST['address'][0] . ' ' . $_POST['address'][1];

echo $address; // prints "111 222"
```

**UPDATE**

Before your script loops through the `$_POST` array, merge the fields, like so:

```
$preformat  = $_POST['Home_Address_1'];
$preformat .= ' ' . $_POST['Home_Address_2'];
$preformat .= ' ' . $_POST['Home_Address_3'];
$_POST['Home_Address_3'] = trim($preformat);
```

Then the last Home Address field contains all three.

Comment: @Justin Can you inspect the DOM and tell me what the name attributes of the three address inputs are?

Comment: IE... When the title of the CSV (in the red) is, Home Address 1... the NAME Attr of the dropdown select statement is, Home_Address_1... as that way when I do the post again I know what goes where. I know this is quite complicated... I will see if I can maybe post a bit more code....

Answer (score 0):

Try array_merge()...http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

Try array_merge with shuffle

```
$merged = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
shuffle($merged);
```

with regards

**Wazzy**